# Java issue on command line data import using data loader

Tags: java, authentication

I am running date import using command line batch file on daily basis for last 3 years without any problem. This morning I get this error

> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to  find valid certification path to requested target
>           at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCert
>   PathBuilder.java:236)
>           at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:194)
>           at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:216)
>           ... 30 more

I updated java and there is no any issue with the browser.

Comment: There have been certificate changes on salesforce's side, you could try to re-download the dataloader executable if that is what you're using with the CLI ?

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I downloaded the latest Data loader. I still get this error.

Comment: I'm absolutely not sure, but my best guess it is related to the certificate changes. There's a success community chatter group about that [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oAF), other resources are [how to prepare your salesforce service for certificate changes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/security_certificate_changes.pdf)

Comment: and [HTTPS Security Certificate Change from SHA-1 to SHA-256 hash algorithms](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=HTTPS-Security-Certificate-Switch-from-SHA-1-to-SHA-256-hash-algorithms&language=en_US)